# how to decode video streaming by using media codec

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediacodec

I have to implement video streaming.i record video i should decode video.i am using media codec to decode video but it shows me error like this

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.media.MediaCodec
```

what is the reason for this error? or if some other idea you have , plz share me

Comment: What version of Android is running on your device?  `MediaCodec` was introduced in Android 4.1 (API 16).

Comment: ya it works on api 17

Comment: now it shows this error java.nio.BufferOverflowException  at java.nio.Buffer.checkPutBounds

Comment: You're attempting to put more data into a `ByteBuffer` than it can hold.  This can happen if you try to write too much data, or the buffer's position is too far into the buffer.